# Returning the other value of boolean enum

Tags: c#, comparative-review

I have a class with a "mode" state. There are currently two modes and we are *not* likely to add more in the future.

The class has a `CurrentMode` property, and a function to swap to the other mode.
I have implemented this using another property called `ModeNotInUse` which returns the opposite value of `CurrentMode`.

However, I am in two minds about how to implement this `ModeNotInUse`

```
public enum PlayerMode
{
    Puzzle,
    Action
}

public class ModeController
{
    public PlayerMode CurrentMode { get; private set; }

   
    private PlayerMode ModeNotInUse => ...


    public void SwitchMode()
    {
        CurrentMode = ModeNotInUse
    }

}
```

My two implimentations of this are:

```
private PlayerMode ModeNotInUse 
   => CurrentMode switch
   {
       PlayerMode.Puzzle => PlayerMode.Action,
       _ => PlayerMode.Puzzle
   };
```

Or

```
private PlayerMode ModeNotInUse 
    => CurrentMode == PlayerMode.Puzzle 
        ? PlayerMode.Action 
        : PlayerMode.Puzzle;
```

Which better captures my intent here? The first is my preference but I worry it's difficult to read.

---

*(edit)*
I could of course do this with a backing boolean field but that feels even less clean

```
private bool inPuzzleMode;
public PlayerMode CurrentMode
{
    get => inPuzzleMode switch
        {
            true => PlayerMode.Puzzle,
            false => PlayerMode.Action
        };
    private set => inPuzzleMode = value == PlayerMode.Puzzle;
}

private PlayerMode ModeNotInUse 
   =>  inPuzzleMode switch
   {
       true => PlayerMode.Action,
       false => PlayerMode.Puzzle
   };
```

Which do you think is best?

Comment: Kind of off topic, but I find that I prefer `ModeInUse`, so that I don't end up with `! ModeNotInUse`.

Comment: It's suspicious to me that you'd need the mode that is currently not in use outside of the ModeController...

Comment: @Vogel612 oh yes, that's a typo, really embarrassed that I missed that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a method would be better than a property in this case. However, I would do it this way :

```
public class ModeController
{
    public PlayerMode CurrentMode { get; private set; }

    public void SwitchMode() 
          => CurrentMode == PlayerMode.Puzzle ? PlayerMode.Action : PlayerMode.Puzzle;
}
```

if the `PlayerMode` is used in different classes, and you want to get the opposite mode, then you can move `SwitchMode()` into an extension :

```
public static class Extension {
    public static PlayerMode  SwitchMode(this PlayerMode current) 
            => current == PlayerMode.Puzzle ? PlayerMode.Action : PlayerMode.Puzzle;    
}

public class ModeController
{
    public PlayerMode CurrentMode { get; private set; }

    public void SwitchMode() => CurrentMode = CurrentMode.SwitchMode();
}
```

if there is a requirement where you want to know the old mode, then you could store the old mode before switching it, and add another method to get the old mode.

Answer (score 4):

First, kudos to you for using an `enum` even though it would be very tempting to just use a `bool` in its place. Not enough can be said for semantic programming.

Second, I would use your first method, but perhaps extract it to an extension method:

```
public static PlayerMode NotInUse(this PlayerMode currentMode) => currentMode switch
{
    PlayerMode.Puzzle => PlayerMode.Action,
    _ => PlayerMode.Puzzle
};
```

Comment: User system terminology - best way to say what the code means.  However a more-or-less [leaky abstraction](https://blog.codinghorror.com/all-abstractions-are-failed-abstractions/) is inevitable. Whatever he vote counts, the "best" answer will start from "semantic programming" and end with "comments and (automated) tests."

Answer (score 3):

How about simply just this?

```
=> (PlayerMode)((CurrentMode + 1) % 2);
```

Here you are taking advantage of the underlying values: 0 and 1.

---

**UPDATE #1**

I think if you look at this problem for the domain perspective then the whole idea of `ModeNotInUse` is pointless. Since if you want to branch based on the mode then you

- either use `CurrentMode == PlayerMode.Puzzle`
- or `CurrentMode != PlayerMode.Puzzle`

and you have covered all cases without introducing a redundant property.

My solution is more fragile than others because if you set explicitly the value for the PlayerMode enums (different than the default ones) then it will not work anymore. For example:

```
public enum PlayerMode
{
    Puzzle = 1,
    Action = 10
}
```

Comment: Too much math, not enough logic

Comment: @jmoreno What do you mean by not enough logic?

Comment: @jmoreno actually I think it's a clever idea, and it's feasible approach since the OP has stated that `PlayerMode` will never have any future changes.

Comment: @iSR5 The current text by the OP reads: "we are not likely to add more in the future". This is a reasonable statement, but it's something you have to rely on consciously, i.e. be aware of the consequences. In this case you could argue that you can always rewrite the logic of the property, should they add another value. If there are other good alternatives though, which are more open for change, I would prefer those.

Comment: "we are not likely to add more in the future" has, in my experience, always meant "within a year or so, we _will_ add more". Anyway, extra values would make "the other mode" a collection of non-selected modes, so that would necessitate a rewrite in any case.

Comment: @PeterCsala: you are doing math on the underlying values, you aren’t making a decision based upon application/domain rules.  This is just the opposite of what the OP did when deciding to use an enum instead of a bool. If it was necessary for performance reasons, that would be fine, a comment could explain what you are doing, but (a) you didn’t include a comment and (b) I doubt it is a performance hotspot.  A ternary statement would read clearer.

Comment: @jmoreno I think if look at this problem for the domain perspective then the whole idea of `ModeNotInUse` is pointless since if you want to branch based on the mode then you either use `CurrentMode == PlayerMode.Puzzle` or `CurrentMode != PlayerMode.Puzzle` and you have covered all cases without introducing a redundant property.

Comment: @jmoreno And yes my solution is more fragile than others since if you set explicitly the value for the `PlayerMode` enums (different than the default ones) then it will not work anymore.

Comment: Both of those comments are good, I would suggest putting them in your answer.

Comment: @jmoreno I've extended

Comment: *if you set explicitly the value for the PlayerMode enums (different than the default ones) then it will not work anymore*  =>  Explicitly setting to 0 and 1 respectively helps to loudly make, or at least strongly imply, this point IMO.

Comment: @radarbob: or 1 and 3….

Comment: @jmoreno, yeah let's play around with it. No problem. I have tes..... uhhh .... crap.